# map и типы информации

Tags: python, функции

Хочу совершить в `map` сразу 2 действия, это сделать все элементы списка типом `float` и возвести их в степень с помощью функции, и в коде ниже все работает, но я хочу код без этой строчки `float_nums = map(f, float_nums)`. В моей голове это выглядит так: `float_nums = map(float + f, str_nums)`, но это собственно так не работает, может можно как-то заменить плюс символом или командой которая сработает?

```
# map() и типы информации

str_nums = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
def f(number):
    return number ** 2

float_nums = map(float, str_nums)
float_nums = map(f, float_nums)
print(list(float_nums))
```

Comment: А Вам точно `map` нужен? Генератор списка часто и понятнее, и короче -  `float_nums = [float(s)**2 for s in str_nums]`

Answer (score 7):

Используйте лямбду

```
str_nums = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
float_nums = list(map(lambda x: float(x) ** 2, str_nums))
print(float_nums)
```

```
[1.0, 4.0, 9.0, 16.0, 25.0]
```

Или обычную функцию

```
def f(number):
    return float(number) ** 2

str_nums = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
float_nums = list(map(f, str_nums))
print(float_nums)
```

Answer (score 4):

Можно два раза подряд применить `map`. Проще вроде нельзя это написать без изменения самой функции и используя только `map`:

```py
float_nums = list(map(f, map(float, str_nums)))
```

Comment: спасибо, это именно то что я искал)

Comment: Всё же перенесу преобразование в `list` тоже сюда из `print`. Всё-таки генераторы такое дело, с ними надо аккуратно.